# Tengo un problema con el cierre de conexiones a MSYQL mediante JAVA.

Tags: java, mysql, mysqlconnector

Después de ejecutar un `prepareStatement` se cierra mi conexión con la base de datos y no me deja seguir ejecutando sentencias.

Me arroja la excepción : `java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.`

Clase Conexión

```
public class ConexionMySql {

private static Connection objConexion = null;
private LoggerRegistros log4j = new LoggerRegistros(this.getClass());

private ConexionMySql() {
    final String user = "root";
    final String pass = "";
    final String server = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
    final String DB = "db_cfprojets";
    final String DriverMySQL = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    final String zonaHoraria = "?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
    try {
        Class.forName(DriverMySQL);
        objConexion = DriverManager.getConnection(server + DB + zonaHoraria, user, pass);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        log4j.setFatal(ex.getMessage(), ex.fillInStackTrace());
    }
}
public static Connection getConnection() {
    if (objConexion == null) {
        new ConexionMySql();
    }
    return objConexion;
}}
```

Método para insertar

```
public void insertClient(Cliente cliente) throws Exception {
    sql = "INSERT INTO tb_cliente VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, cliente.getRfc());
        ps.setString(2, cliente.getNombre());
        ps.setString(3, cliente.getDireccion().getCalle());
        ps.setString(4, cliente.getDireccion().getNum_calle());
        ps.setString(5, cliente.getDireccion().getColonia());
        ps.setInt(6, cliente.getDireccion().getCp());
        ps.setString(7, cliente.getDireccion().getMucipio());
        ps.setString(8, cliente.getDireccion().getEstado());
        ps.setString(9, cliente.getDireccion().getPais());
        ps.setString(10, cliente.getContacto().getNum_movil());
        ps.setString(11, cliente.getContacto().getEmail());
        int a = ps.executeUpdate();
        if (a == 0) {
            loggger.setInformacion("No se actualizo ninguna fila");
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        loggger.setError(ex.getMessage(), ex.fillInStackTrace());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.fillInStackTrace(), ex.getMessage(), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } finally {
        if (con != null) {
            con.close();
        }
         if (ps != null) {
            ps.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir las clases a las que pertenecen los objetos ps y con? Gracias

Comment: ps y con son objetos prepareStatement y connection respectivamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static Connection objConexion = null;
```

y

```
} finally {
  if (con != null) {
    con.close();
  }
```

Solo tienes una única instancia de `Connection`; devuelves esa misma instancia cada vez que haces `getConnection()`, y al ejecutar la primera consulta, cierras esa única conexión. Naturalmente, al ejecutar cualquier otra instrucción mediante esa misma conexión, fallará.

Tres opciones:

- No cerrar nunca la conexión. Tiene el problema de que si hay inactividad se puede cerrar la conexión por timeout. Además, si hay múltiples *threads* usándolo (p.ej. en un servidor web) te dará problemas.
- Crear una conexión cada vez que inicies un proceso de acceso a la BD. Naturalmente, cada *thread* tendrá su propia conexión. Consume más recursos (crear conexiones es lento) pero es razonablemente sencillo si tu programa no es muy complicado. Asegúrate de cerrar todas las conexiones una vez no las necesites.
- Usar un *pool* de conexiones que te mantiene varias conexiones abiertas y te va asignando conexiones según las necesites. Lo más normal es que uses alguno como una librería aparte (p.ej. c3p0) en vez de implementarlo tú. Más complicado, pero la ruta a seguir si estamos hablando de algo que ha de estar continúamente funcionando y abriendo conexiones a la BD.

Para empezar, recomiendo la opción de enmedio.

Comment: Gracias, he allí donde tengo el error al momento de cerrar la conexión ya que me base en el patrón `singleton`para solo instanciar una sola vez la conexión,pero al parecer si voy a crear y cerrar conexiones diferentes, e investigare la librería `c3p0`, Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te puedo decir es que las conexiones pueden `caducar` o `quedarse colgadas`, por eso una variable que almacena una conexión a base de datos y que esta declarada como `static` es una muy mala práctica y te puede causar muchos dolores de  cabeza.

Lo correcto es abrir la conexión, hacer la operación de base de datos y cerrar la conexión. La excepción que confirma esta regla es cuando usas `transacciones`, en ese caso es recomendable mantener abierta la conexión hasta que finalice la transacción. También es recomendable que las conexiones se hagan mediante `pool de conexiones`.

El error que te aparece parece responder a esta situación: Java cree que la conexión esta abierta porque la conexión es `static` pero para mysql la conexión esta inactiva o cerrada. Por eso te contesta `No se permiten operaciones después de la conexión cerrada`.

Comment: Muchas gracias estaba tratando de seguir el patrón  `singleton` para la conexión a la BD. Pero me empezó a dar muchos problemas con el cierre de la misma, hasta ahora quite el `finally {
  if (con != null) {
    con.close();
  }` para poder continuar.